# iTunes Connect thinks my app is for iPad and iPhone, when it's really just for iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store-connect

I have my iPad app (with keyboard extension) ready to go, but when i try to submit it in iTunesConnect, I get an error saying that I need to add screenshots for 4inch screens and 3.5inch screens. It apparently thinks my app is meant for iPhone as well when it is really just for iPad. I have looked at similar issues on this site and I have done exactly what the posts tell me to do. But I still get the same error.

-In my project, under deployment info, I have devices set to iPad.

-In my info.plist I have required device capabilities set to armv7

-In Build settings > deployment I have target device family set to iPad. as well as in my keyboard extension build settings.

I am not sure what else I can effect in order to make iTunesConnect know that my app is only for iPad. Perhaps I am misinterpreting the error all together?

-Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you able to finish submitting the app despite the error?

Comment: Above you said that you set TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY under deployment info to iPad. Did you do this for both your Project and Targets?

Comment: In Xcode, was the project originally created as a Universal app?

Comment: No i originally created it as iPad, because i had similar issues when i had chosen universal in the past. So i thought choosing iPad this time would remedy the problem but it didn't :\

Answer (score 1):

1) You can confirm what iTunes Connect thinks the device family is by clicking the version link and looking at the binary details

[image: an example of a released universal app]

2) Assuming the iTunes Connect inspection verifies that your binary really does think it's universal (or not iPad), confirm that you've changed the device family for your target for release as well as debug:

[image: build settings for release/debug may be collapsed - expand it and confirm when in doubt]

If the device family is correct at iTunes Connect, then you know the interpretation of the message is off and something else is going on.